# Where is .NET Framework 4.5 directory located?

Tags: windows-7, .net-framework, .net-4.0, .net-4.5

I installed .NET Framework 4.5 on Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 64 bit. When I looked in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework (Framework64)` directory, I did not see any directory containing files of .NET Framework 4.5, just those:

- v1.0.3705
- v1.1.4322
- v2.0.50727
- v3.0
- v3.5
- v4.0.30319

[Installing the .NET Framework 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5a4x27ek.aspx) says:

> The .NET Framework 4.5 replaces the .NET Framework 4. When you install the .NET Framework 4.5 on a system that has the .NET Framework 4 installed, the assemblies are replaced.

Thereby,  4.5's files are located in v4.0.30319 directory. Am I right?

Comment: I found complete answer to my question. http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/Mar/13/NET-45-is-an-inplace-replacement-for-NET-40

Comment: I would create an answer based on that blog post.  The problem I have with it is that its based 8 month old information.  So I won't be doing that as the information besides being answered by a support article on the Microsoft website is currently incorrect

Comment: The answer is yes. you can check this blog post from [scott hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NETVersioningAndMultiTargetingNET45IsAnInplaceUpgradeToNET40.aspx)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Both 4.5 and 4.51 are in-place upgrades, which means they replace the previous version (4 or 4.5). The files are overwritten and these framework versions do not have their own directory but are stored in 'v4.0.30319'

So your assumption was absolutely correct.